# I have problem with crud in my code and command

Tags: html, laravel, crud

when pressing the command php artisan route: list does not appear the addresses to perform the crud in my code.

```
|        | GET|HEAD | /                      |                  | App\Http\Controllers\CarController@casa                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | crear                  | cars.create      | App\Http\Controllers\CarController@mostrar                             | web          |
|        | POST     | crear                  | cars.crear       | App\Http\Controllers\CarController@crear                               | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                   | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST     | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | password/reset         | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
```

**Routes/web.php**

```
<?php 

Route::get('/crear',[ 'uses'=>'CarController@mostrar', 'as'=>'cars.create' ] ); 
Route::post('/crear',[ 'uses'=>'CarController@crear', 'as'=>'cars.crear' ]); 
Route::get('/', 'CarController@casa' ); 
Auth::routes(); 
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: show your web.php of route folder

Comment: <?php


Route::get('/crear',[
    'uses'=>'CarController@mostrar',
    'as'=>'cars.create'
]   
);
Route::post('/crear',[
    'uses'=>'CarController@crear',
    'as'=>'cars.crear'


]);

Route::get('/', 'CarController@casa' );


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Comment: So you want to do crud of addresses?

Comment: make a resource controller then see `route:list`

Comment: If you already have your route into the web.php file, it's probably because you have use that command `php artisan route:cache`. If so, you have to clear your cache or recache it. I will use `php artisan route:clear`, since you are in production and will have to add more route to your app. Caching your route is good in production or for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in cmd : `php artisan make:controller AddressController --resource`

and add this in web.php, `Route::resource('address', 'AddressController');`

Now, you will get crud list while doing route:list